# how secure is sending values through urls in PHP

Tags: php

I want to know how secure is about sending values through URLs. It will be a big mess I think. The good suggestion would be sending values by post method in php through pages. But if I get a better example of how usually the script would be in post format it would be great.. Or otherwise suggest your valuable comments to this to do how

Comment: This question is unclear, please state what security you need and what for. What are these values you want to send through pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GET:** User can directly see the data in the browser location bar.

**POST:** Anyone in the intermediate network between client and server can still see the data.

**Solution:** If you want ultimate security, you need to use SSL (HTTPS). It's *not* free, you need to buy the SSL certificate first.

---

**[EDIT]: OP Clarification:**

"Anyone in the intermediate network" means that suppose you are connected to your company's Internet Firewall that connects to to your Internet Service Provider (ISP) which connects to the server your website is hosted on.

Now, if you do not use SSL, then your company administrators can see the data through firewall and also ISP administrators can see it, if they want.

Comment: so is SSL is enabled in the server and we pass POST data then it will be secure from outside world, right

Comment: what do you meant to say "Anyone in the intermediate network between client and server". Can you breif it with one example

Comment: Yes, if user connects to your site through HTTPS, then all data is secured from outside world.

Comment: @Col, the problem is the anxiety of new developers towards security and unclear concepts. :)